# Should I delete pointer from `new` passed to a function which makes into a `shared_ptr`?

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

In the following code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
};

class Bar{
public:
    void addFoo(Foo *foo){
        auto my_foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.addFoo(new Foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Do I need to clean up the pointer created in `main()` by the `bar.addFoo(new Foo)` call, or will this be taken care of by `Bar` which creates a `shared_ptr` of it?  My understanding is that `auto my_foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo);` will use the copy constructer to copy this pointer into `my_foo` leaving the original one dangling, is that correct?

Comment: You don't, this code is correct as written. But be careful: if for some reason an exception is thrown before `std::shared_ptr` is constructed, you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks.  To prevent the memory leak on exception should I rather explicitly declare a new variable, pass a pointer to it and wrap `bar.addFoo(new *Foo) in a try catch?

Comment: A better way is to not pass a raw pointer at all. Why do you want to pass a raw pointer?

Comment: No specific reason.  Should I rather create a shared pointer in `main` instead?  I am just unsure where the ownership ends up if I create a shared_ptr in one scope and pass it to another one.

Comment: @Paul - With shared_ptr's the ownership is shared.  :-)  They own the element collectively, and the last one to leave turns off the light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very idea of a constructor taking a raw pointer is to pass the ownership to `std::shared_ptr`. So, no, you don't have to `delete` a raw pointer passed to `std::shared_ptr`. Doing this will lead to a double deletions, which is UB.

Note that in general passing a raw pointer is dangerous. Consider the following more generalized example:

```
void addFoo(Foo *foo){
        // some code which could throw an exception
        auto my_foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo);
    }
```

If an exception is throw before `my_foo` is constructed, `foo` will leak.

If you have no special reason to pass a raw pointer, consider the following alternative:

```
class Bar {
public:
    template<class... Args>
    void addFoo(Args... args){
        auto my_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(args...);
    }  
};

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.addFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

Here you pass arguments (if you have any) to construct `Foo` inside `addFoo()` instead of constructing `Foo` before invoking `addFoo()`.

Perfect forwarding of `args...` could be used if it is needed:

```
    template<class... Args>
    void addFoo(Args&&... args){
        auto my_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe universal references with perfect forwarding would be suited here?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer In general, yes. Let me add it.

Answer (score 4):

The code you wrote is correct.  But in modern C++, you should not be using raw pointers, `new` and `delete` unless you have to interoperate with code that does.  If you can help it (and if question comments are any indication, you can), use smart pointers all the way through:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {};

class Bar {
public:
    void addFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) {
        auto my_foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(foo));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.addFoo(std::make_unique<Foo>());
    return 0;
}
```

Above, the `addFoo` member function receives the pointer as a `unique_ptr`, and uses [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to transfer ownership of the pointer from the `unique_ptr` to the `shared_ptr` without copying the referent; after constructing the `shared_ptr`, the `unique_ptr` is left in an empty state.  You could also have `addFoo` receive a `shared_ptr` directly, or construct the object in-place inside the member function, as in Evg’s answer.

Using `unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer makes it clear that the method intends to take ownership of the allocation, and encourages callers to use smart pointers themselves, making it less likely they will forget to `delete` their allocations later.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a sentence about std::move for transferring the unique pointer to shared pointer

Answer (score 3):

A raw pointer does not manage end of life, but a shared pointer does. When you create a shared pointer from a raw pointer, the shared pointer *takes ownership* of the object. That means that the object will be destroyed when the last shared pointer pointing to it will go out of scope.

In your code, `my_foo` takes ownership of the object created with `new Foo()`, goes out of scope when `addFoo` returns, and as it contains the only shared reference, correctly destroys the object.

Answer (score 0):

The correct, c++ way to do this, would be the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{

};

class Bar{
public:
    void addFoo(Foo foo){
        auto my_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(foo);
    }
    
};

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.addFoo(Foo());
    return 0;
}
```

This avoids any raw pointers or naked new, and is totally exception safe. Also, `std::make_shared` introduces some performance benefits.
One confusing thing here is that the code seems to be unnecessarily copy the `Foo` object, however, since C++17, due to Return Value Optimization, (RVO), you are guaranteed to have no copies at all (when passing `Foo` as an argument to `addFoo`).

Comment: There will always be at least one copy. You create a `Foo` on the stack in main, then copy-construct a `shared_ptr` from it. @Evg's answer shows a more idiomatic approach.

Comment: So, one last question about this.  In the solution above, a `Foo()` is created on the stack and then in `Bar()` a `shared_ptr` is created that references this object on the stack.  Should `Foo()` not rather be created on the heap?  I guess this is what @Evg's solution alludes to?

Comment: @Paul No, Foo() is created on the stack, then copied onto the heap by ```std::make_shared()```. @Evg solution is a bit better, since it never creates ```Foo()``` onto the stack, rather just passes arguments onto it. Though if you have an existing lvalue ```Foo``` on the stack, you have to copy it.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the shared pointer with make_shared. If you want to construct Foo in main (e.g. because you have the paramters available there), then use make_shared at the point of construction and pass the shared_ptr on.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo destructed" << std::endl; }
};

class Bar{
public:
    void addFoo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo){
        auto my_foo = foo;
    }        
};

int main() {
    auto bar = Bar();
    bar.addFoo(std::make_shared<Foo>());
    return 0;
}
```

delete also calls your destructor. You can test, whether the shared pointer destructs your object or whether a delete is needed by printing out a message.

Comment: Please leave a comment, whoever voted down. Thank you.